# Getting AV video from RGB or VGA or HDMI

Tags: display, rgb

Which is the simplest option? In order to get  Composite video with NTSC/PAL video we will use a CS5213 to convert HDMI to VGA, then use some resistors to get  Composite video with NTSC/PAL. Then I realized that there may be a way to get  Composite video with NTSC/PAL from RGB.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "AV" here? Composite video with NTSC/PAL/SECAM colors?

Comment: Just get an open scan converter or something; what you're asking to do is a *much* bigger job than you think.

Comment: Yes I mean  Composite video with NTSC/PAL by AV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "use some resistors" to get composite video out of VGA signals - not unless the VGA signal is standard definition, timed exactly to match your desired composite video standard, and then the composite video would be monochrome. Color requires active components - a passive resistor network won't do.

CS5213 doesn't have a frame buffer: it outputs the VGA signals synchronously with the incoming HDMI signal. The output timing and resolution won't match any composite video standard. You'll need to use a chip that has a video rescaler - it'll input the HDMI or VGA/RGB data into a frame buffer memory, and then output is slowly as a composite video (what you call "AV").

Comment: Thanks for your support. Do you know any IC which converts HDMI to Composite Video

Comment: @FSA there is no single chip to do that. And even if there were, what would you use it for?

Comment: We have device, our customers connect it to AV screen 7 inch which use in vehicle. Now we design a new device but SoC has no AV out. This is why.

Comment: @FSA What resolution are you outputting via HDMI? Can you control the HDMI output to be NTSC or PAL format? Then there are simple solutions that don't need memory that will take HDMI to composite video.

Comment: If you want a "plug and play" solution, an HDMI-to-AV converter [like this one](https://www.amazon.com/Converter-Composite-Adapter-Supports-Blu-Ray/dp/B0814Z34XG) will do. It's inexpensive. You can always look what chipset it uses and try to duplicate the functionality.

Comment: Hi, firt of all thanks for your help, we will use chip to design it on board. 
We were using CM4, now we cannot even buy it. Now, we design a board with RK3568 which is great. But there is no documentation. And our customers use cheap display, so we need output for Composite Video. 

I think it is possible to arrange HDMI resolution.

Comment: http://en.macrosilicon.com/info.asp?base_id=2&third_id=17 
This chip converts RGB to Composite Video. This might work with RGB output of RK3568.